# Getting the latest 'role-switch' timestamp from a messages table

Tags: mysql

**Problem**

I am looking at trying to get the lowest timestamp (earliest) after the 'side' has changed in a ticket conversation, to see how long it has been since the first reply to the latest message.

**Example:**

```
A (10:00) : Hello
A (10:05) : How are you?
B (10:06) : I'm fine, thank you
B (10:08) : How about you?
A (10:10) : I'm fine too, thank you <------
A (10:15) : I have to go now, see you around!
```

Now what I am looking for is the timestamp of the message indicated by the arrow. The first message after the 'side' of the conversation changed, in this case from user to support.

Example data from table "messages":

```
mid    conv_id   uid    created_at   message                           type
2750   1         3941   1341470051   Hello                             support
3615   1         3941   1342186946   How are you?                      support
4964   1         2210   1343588022   I'm fine, thank you               user
4965   1         2210   1343588129   How about you?                    user
5704   1         3941   1344258743   I'm fine too, thank you           support
5706   1         3941   1344258943   I have to go now, see you around! support
```

**What I have tried so far:**

```
select
n.nid AS `node_id`,
(
    SELECT m_inner.created_at
    FROM messages m_inner
    WHERE m_inner.mid = messages.mid AND
    CASE
        WHEN MAX(m_support.created_at) < MAX(m_user.created_at) THEN -- latest reply from user
            m_support.created_at
        ELSE
            m_user.created_at
    END <= m_inner.created_at
    ORDER BY messages.created_at ASC
    LIMIT 0,1
) AS `latest_role_switch_timestamp`
from
node n
left join messages m on n.nid = messages.nid
left join messages m_user on n.nid = m_user.nid and m_user.type = 'user'
left join messages m_support on n.nid = m_support.nid and m_support.type = 'support'
GROUP BY messages.type, messages.nid
ORDER BY messages.nid, messages.created_at DESC
```

**Preferred result:**

```
node_id    latest_role_switch_timestamp
1          1344258743
```

But this has not yielded any results for the subquery. Am I looking in the right direction or should I try something else? I don't know if this would be possible in mysql.

Also this uses a subquery, which, for performance reasons, is not ideal, considering this query will probably be used in overviews, meaning it would have to run that subquery for every message in the overview.

If you require any more information, please tell me, as I am at my wit's end

Comment: There is no "conversation_id" column? Does the messages table store one giant conversation?

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I will edit the main post to reflect details, there is a conversation_id. Thank you for pointing it out

Comment: OK, next question. Do you want the last change for every conversation in one query? And just confirming you don't want the whole row, just the timestamp?

Comment: If that is possible, I would want the 'latest_role_switch' if you can call it that, for every conversation in one query, per conversation.

Comment: why dont you write a sql procedure for doing the same?

Comment: Because I had not thought of that and would not know how I would do that, I'll have to look into mysql procedures then. But if that is the only way to do this, I'll keep it at php to do this, I do not know if that is faster or not, but it will take me longer to learn  how to do this in a mysql procedure than to do it in PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the table to a max-date summary of itself to get the messages of the last block, then use mysql's special group-by support to pick the *first* row from those for each conversation:

```
select * from (
 select * from (
  select m.*
  from messages m
  join (
    select conv_id, type, max(created_at) last_created
    from messages
    group by 1,2) x
    on x.conv_id = m.conv_id
    and x.type != m.type
    and x.last_created < m.created_at) y
 order by created_at) z
group by conv_id
```

This returns the *whole* row that was the first message of the last block.

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d74c7/6).

Performance will be pretty good, because there are no correlated subqueries.

Comment: Wow, that looks complicated, I'll have to look at how that works after this. I'm going to try it out on my data and I'll report back here :P

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works like a charm! Marked as answer and I'll have to look into how this query works, as this looks interesting :)